# AVPlayer stops playing when screen locks

Tags: ios, avplayer

99.9% of the time, my app has no issue playing audio (via `AVPlayer`) while it's in the background/the screen is locked, etc.

But once in a blue moon , it will stop playing when the screen locks. I noticed that the sound fades out rather than abruptly stopping. I can go back into the app, press pause and play a few times, but it continues to happen. I also tried playing from Spotify to make sure it wasn't a system issue, but Spotify worked fine.

I have not been able to reproduce this while at a computer. What could cause this? How could I troubleshoot it? Thanks.

Comment: i am facing the same issue, do you find any solution/workaround?

Comment: @AbuzarAmin sorry, nope

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know if this can help you to fix this issue.

As in documentation, you have to setup your app's AVAudioSession, as it is "An intermediary object that communicates to the system how you intend to use audio in your app. (See: [Apple Developers Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession)"
So, to let the system know what your app wants to do with the audio (EG. I'm programming a stream radio player), I had to declare in my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
{
...
   do{
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
      try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
   }catch{
    ...
   }
...
}
```

Now, when my app goes to background, and even when the screen locked, the music keeps playing in background.

Hope this helps.